# TypeConverters and null

Tags: c#, typeconverter

I am using a class to store connection strings. My app reads a setting from the settings class and assigns it to an instance variable. This is then bound to some controls. My connection string class has the following attribute set:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ConnectionStringConverter))]
```

My type convertor looks like is below.

The problem is that if the settings in the settings file is blank the settings class returns null. and not an instance of my connection string class using the default constructor.

Please could someone help me in solving this riddle.

Thanks.

```
public class ConnectionStringConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;
        else
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
            return (ConnectionString)(value as string);
        else
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return (string)(value as ConnectionString);
        else
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't fix it.  If you don't have a connection string in the settings then there's no hope that you can create one yourself that works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here:

```
public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
    CultureInfo culture, object value)
{
    // The first condition.
    if (value is string)
        return (ConnectionString)(value as string);
    else
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
}
```

Let's break down the conditional statement:

```
if (value is string)
```

This is fine, this is where you're doing the conversion from string to your `ConnectionString` class.

```
return (ConnectionString)(value as string);
```

This is the problem line.  If `value` is null, then `value as string` is null as well and you are returning a null reference.

Instead, you want to do this:

```
return (ConnectionString)(value as string) ?? new ConnectionString();
```

In the event that `value` is null, the [coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) will provide the instance of your `ConnectionString` class called with the default-parameterless constructor.